# How does dot operator work on struct vs pointer to struct?

Tags: go

This might a basic in Go.
How does the dot `.` operator work on struct vs pointer to struct?

```
type cc struct {
  x int
}

func main() {
    obj := cc{x:2}
    ptr := &cc{x:3}
    
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %v\n", obj.x) // Hello, 2
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %v\n", ptr.x) // Hello, 3
}
```

How is it able to access the field in both cases above?

Answer (score 4):

The compiler adds the necessary indirection automatically for pointer receivers. Thus, `ptr.x` is the same as `(*ptr).x`

> https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors

Answer (score 2):

It is simply allowed by the language specifications, [Selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors):

> 1. For a value `x` of type `T` **or `*T`** where T is not a pointer or interface type, `x.f` denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in `T` where there is such an f. [...]
> 2. [...]
> 3. [...], if the type of `x` is a defined pointer type and `(*x).f` is a
>    valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), `x.f` is
>    shorthand for `(*x).f`.

In your example, `ptr` is of a defined pointer type `*cc` and `(*cc).f` is a valid selector based on rule 1, therefore rule 3 applies.